# Efficient way to store the terms of a summation in a list?

Tags: matrix, parallelization

I have two matrices, `A` and `B` of the same dimension $Nr\times Nc$, with $Nr\gg Nc$.
Essentially, I am trying to put all the terms of the sum $$\sum_i^{Nr}\sum_{n,m}^{Nc}(A_{i,n}-B_{i,m}+1)$$
into a list.

The most direct way I know to do this, is with `Table`:

```
Table[A[[i, n]] - B[[i, m]] + 1, {i, 1, Nr}, {n, 1,Nc}, {m, 1, Nc}]
```

However, because `Nr` is quite large, I am trying to find a more effective way to do this. I tried replacing `Table` with `ParallelTable`, but this takes longer.
Is `Table` the best way to do this?

Following the suggestion by @flinty, this is an example of what I expect:

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
B = {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}};
Nr = 3; Nc = 2;

Result=Table[A[[i, n]] - B[[i, m]] + 1, {i, 1, Nr}, {n, 1, Nc}, {m, 1, Nc}]
```

Then I use `Flatten[Result,2]` and get:

```
{-5, -6, -4, -5, -5, -6, -4, -5, -5, -6, -4, -5}
```

**Maybe there is a way to do this without 3 iterators?**

Comment: Please provide some short example inputs and outputs to demonstrate what you're expecting.

Comment: I think it is clearer now, thank you for the suggestion @flinty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The elements of the sum can be written in matrix form as $A \otimes 1_{1 \times Nc} - 1_{1 \times Nc} \otimes B + 1_{Nr \times Nc^2}$, where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html).  In Mathematica, this is

```
e = ConstantArray[1, {1, Nc}];
Result2 = KroneckerProduct[A + 1, e] - KroneckerProduct[e, B];
```

Here's a performance comparison:

```
Nr = 1000; Nc = 50;
A = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {Nr, Nc}];
B = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {Nr, Nc}];

RepeatedTiming[
Result=Table[A[[i,n]]-B[[i,m]]+1,{i,1,Nr},{n,1,Nc},{m,1,Nc}];,
10
] (* {3.09477, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[
(e=ConstantArray[1, {1, Nc}];Result2=KroneckerProduct[A+1,e]-KroneckerProduct[e,B];),
10
] (* {0.025702, Null} *)

Flatten[Result] == Flatten[Result2] (* True *)
```

On my machine with $1000\times 50$ matrices, it's about 120 times faster than the Table-based method.

Comment: This works perfectly. I am using  $10,000 \times 9$ matrices and it is about $140$ times faster than with `Table`. Thank you @Steven.

Comment: I think it would be valuable to have a generalization of this method. What if instead of $A_{i,n}-B_{i,m}+1$ we have an arbitrary function $F[A_{i,n},B_{i,m}]$?  Would it be best to make it a new question?

Comment: If $F$ is Listable, you could pass $A \otimes 1_{1 \times Nc}$ and $1_{1 \times Nc} \otimes B$ as args and it should have similar performance.

Answer (score 8):

This is faster, but not by even an order of magnitude:

```
myFunc[a_, b_] := 1 + a - b;
MapThread[Outer[myFunc, ##] &, {A, B}]
```